# Possible data leakage or Overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I've asked my question in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882631/possible-data-leakage-or-overfitting/62883254#62883254). I've built a classification model using random forests and I'm getting a very high cv accuracy scores which make me belive it is either overfitting or some kind of data leakage occurred. Can someone please explain to me what might be the issue?. Thanks

Comment: You have responses in your other question, why are you asking here?

Comment: I'm still not sure if those suggestions have solved my problem

Comment: Things that are not correct. 1) standardizing X_train and then do cross-validation: you have to  estimate mean and sd from the training set only and you use them to scale both training and validation test. 2) you are applying SMOTE on the entire X_train and then running cross-validation: you are using information from the validation set to augment the training data. You need to apply SMOTE on the only training set of each round of the cross-validation. 3) Performances must be evaluated only on the validation test, not the oversampled validation set.